# Show/hide div with radio button using Jquery Cookie

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, show-hide

I have a form with radio buttons. When I click on a radio button an appropriate div shows up. When the page loads all divs are hidden. It works fine for me.

But how to modify this code  using jquery cookie plugin to remember last selection of radio button and show an appropriate div after page is refreshing.

```
<form id='form-id'>
  <input name='test' type='radio' value="a" />A
  <br />
  <input name='test' type='radio' value="b" />B
  <br />
  <input name='test' type='radio' value="c" />C
</form>
<div id='show-me' style='display:none'>Hello</div>
<div id='show-me2' style='display:none'>Hello2</div>
<div id='show-me3' style='display:none'>Hello3</div>   

<script>   
  $("input[name='test']").click(function () {
    $('#show-me').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'a') ? 'block':'none');
    $('#show-me2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'b') ? 'block':'none');
    $('#show-me3').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'c') ? 'block':'none');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
// On reload apply the previous selection kept in cookie 
if($.cookie('selected') && $.cookie('shown')){
  $("input[name='test']"+"[value='"+$.cookie('selected')+"']").prop('checked', true)
  $("#"+$.cookie('shown')).css('display', 'block')
}

$("input[name='test']").click(function () {     
  $('#show-me').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'a') ? 'block':'none');
  $('#show-me2').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'b') ? 'block':'none');
  $('#show-me3').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'c') ? 'block':'none');

  $.cookie('selected', $(this).val()) //Keep selected element in cookie
  $.cookie('shown', $('div:visible').attr("id")) //Keep shown element in cookie
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this modification doen's work for me. The content of div doesn't show up by clicking on radio button.

Comment: @spinet: When doesn't it show up by clicking? Before the reload or after? Is there an error thrown?

Comment: Doens't show up neither before nor after. No errors are shown.

Comment: What is your browser? I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtta1w9k/14/) that works for me for you to check. :)

Comment: Thank you. Now it works for me. Perhaps I did something wrong.